# Google Cloud run deploy via command line failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

While deploying cloud run container I am getting following error in command line.

```
Commond: gcloud beta run deploy <<myapp>> --image gcr.io/abc-123/<<containername>>:5 --platform managed --region us-east1

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.
```

It was working fine few days back , stopped working now. From Ui deployment is working. Only issue is with command line.

Is anyone else facing same issue?

I also tried this command

```
 gcloud beta run services list --platform managed
```

and got following error

```
WARNING: The following Cloud Run regions did not respond: asia-east1, asia-northeast1, asia-northeast2, australia-southeast1, europe-west1, europe-west4, northamerica-northeast1, us-east1, us-west1. List results may be incomplete.
Listed 0 items.
```

Comment: 1) You are specifying a tag when deploying. Does that container image with tag `5` exist? Tags are usually 10 digit hex numbers 2) Edit your question and show the command and output that pushed the image (`gcloud builds submit`). 3) Include the output from `gcloud container images list`

Comment: Yes, tag exists, it was working before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to duplicate this issue in my one project. I created a simple Hello World application, packaged it into a container image, uploaded the container image to Container Registry, and then I deployed the container image to Cloud Run.

I only followed the [Quick Start guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python_1) for Build and Deploy.

I executed something like:

```
gcloud beta run deploy <SERVICE> --image gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<IMAGE_NAME> --platform managed --region us-east1
```

Here are my results:

```
Allow unauthenticated invocations to [<SERVICE>] (y/N)?  y
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [<SERVICE>] in project [<PROJECT_ID>] region [us-east1]
✓ Deploying new service... Done.                                                           
  ✓ Creating Revision...                  
  ✓ Routing traffic...
  ✓ Setting IAM Policy...
Done.
Service [<SERVICE>] revision [<SERVICE>-00001-var] has been deployed and is serving 100 percent of traffic at https://<SERVICE>-xxxxxxx-ue.a.run.app
```

I recommend running your command with the flag --log-http in order to get more information about where it is failing, also you can execute your command with --verbosity to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on log-http. It is trying to test  https://run.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/projects/abc-254202/locations/asia-northeast1/services/aaaaa:testIamPermissions?alt=json  and then giving that error . may be they introduced new IAM rules. I will check. Can you try to deploy the revision on same service? Just run the same command again

Comment: Try this as well . gcloud beta run services list --platform managed